# DidSelect Annotation getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a tap gesture recognizer added to a mapView.  My MapView has annotations and when I tap on an annotation only `dismissCollectionView` is called.  DidSelectAnnotation method not getting called.  How do I stop tapgesture method(dismisscollection) calling when I tap on an annotation?  Any help will be appreciated.

```
self.m_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    self.m_mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    self.m_mapView.delegate = self;

   // MapHeight = self.m_mapView.frameHeight;

    m_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        [m_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [m_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    self.m_mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    [self.m_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];
    [self.m_bgImageView addSubview:self.m_mapView];

    m_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    m_locationManager.delegate = self;


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissCollectionView)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.m_mapView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want both actions to happen**: Set the delegate of your gesture recognizer and implement [`gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) to return `YES` for your recognizer and any that the map view uses internally.

**If you want `dismissCollectionView` and `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` to be mutually exclusive**:  Implement [`-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:) and check if the touch location is in an `MKAnnotationView` or one of its subviews.  Only return `YES` if the location is outside all annotation views.